# Multistore magento error: Call to a member function getDefaultCurrencyCode()

Tags: magento2.3, module, multistore, nginx, php-7.3

I have a running version of magento 2.3, php 7.3 and nginx.
The default store and another store work fine and are displayed correctly.

Whenever i try to use a different store code other than the 2 working, I receive a PHP error upon loading the page.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getDefaultCurrencyCode() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php:146 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(101): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->updateContext(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor)) 
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) 
#4 /var/w in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php on line 146
```

The php files in the stack trace are still untouched, so default.

My nginx config for the multistore is:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
        site_not_working.server.local site_not_working_nl_20;
        site_not_working2.server.local site_not_working2_nl_7;
        site_working.server.local site_working_nl_26;
        default_working.com default;
}


server {
        listen 80;
        server_name default_working.com site_working.local site_not_working2.server.local site_not_working.server.local;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2/;
        include /var/www/html/general_configs/nginx.conf;
}
```

The included conf is:

```
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;

location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}
location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    #added fastcgi params for store support
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    #fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;

    include        fastcgi_params;

}

include /var/www/html/magento2/pub/ub-tool/nginx.conf;
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

My php conf for the .sock-file is

```
[magento]
user = magento
group = magento
listen = /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-magento.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 7
chdir = /
```

Is anyone able to notice what is causing the error on the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was resolved by replacing the line

```
$defaultStore->getDefaultCurrencyCode()
```

to

```
$store->getDefaultCurrencyCode()
```

in the file /vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php